# extend background width of div to include browser width

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have a number of DIVs in my default page...fullContent etc...

I would like to extend the background colour of the products div to include the full width of the browser...is this possible?

```
<div id="Products" style="background-color:red;">
   <div id="secondPageDiv" class="wrapper" style="width: 70%; font-size:22px;">
      text text text
   </div>
   <div class="images" style="width: 30%; ">
       <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/laptop_20150210160627.png" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: iv tried background-size:cover & contain

Comment: By default the width of a DIV should fill it's parent element unless specified otherwise, but you haven't shown enough code here to make a judgement.

Comment: If you set your HTML and BODY tags to be 100% width, and there is no code between those and this snippet you should be OK. If you are working within some sort of centred page container you are in for a little bit of fun!

Comment: fun he says...reason for causing insanity perhaps :P

Answer (score 0):

You should add a "width: 100%;" to your product div. Knowing that its parent elements must have a width of 100% too (including body).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<div id="Products" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background-color:red;">
        <div id="secondPageDiv" class="wrapper" style="width: 70%; font-size:22px;">
text text text
        </div>
        <div class="images" style="width: 30%; ">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/laptop_20150210160627.png" />
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple tweak will surely help:

```
#Products {
    box-shadow: -500px 0px 0px 0px red, 500px 0px 0px 0px red;
    }
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8usabfo/1/)**